# Error running the open information extraction given by Stanford

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to run the openIE given by stanford nlp using the command given in the official website: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml

```
java -mx1g -cp stanford-openie.jar:stanford-openie-models.jar edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE  mytextfile.txt
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<clinit>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:99)
at edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE.main(OpenIE.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 2 more
```

Again when I run the java code given:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.RelationTriple;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class OpenIEDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
// Create the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,natlog,openie");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

// Annotate an example document.
Annotation doc = new Annotation("Obama was born in Hawaii. He is our president.");
pipeline.annotate(doc);

// Loop over sentences in the document
for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {

  // Get the OpenIE triples for the sentence
  Collection<RelationTriple> triples = sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class);

  // Print the triples
  for (RelationTriple triple : triples) {
    System.out.println(triple.confidence + "\t" +
        triple.subjectLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
        triple.relationLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
        triple.objectLemmaGloss());
  }

  // Alternately, to only run e.g., the clause splitter:
  List<SentenceFragment> clauses = new OpenIE(props).clausesInSentence(sentence);
  for (SentenceFragment clause : clauses) {
    System.out.println(clause.parseTree);
  }
}
}
}
```

I get the next error:

```
Adding annotator tokenize
TokenizerAnnotator: No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0,7 sec].
Adding annotator depparse
Loading depparse model file: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_UD.gz ... 
PreComputed 100000, Elapsed Time: 1.159 (s)
Initializing dependency parser done [3,5 sec].
Adding annotator natlog
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "natlog" requires annotator "parse"
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:297)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:126)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:122)
at stnfrd.OpenIEDemo.main(OpenIEDemo.java:33)
/home/ue/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the first error, you are missing the slf4j library. Can you post the whole error instead of just those pieces?

Comment: I will modify the question to show the whole code

Comment: Maybe add the link you got your instructions from as well

Comment: I guess that it is clearer now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The first error is you don't have the slf4j jar, which is currently included in the latest version on GitHub: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP or you can find that specific jar here: http://www.slf4j.org/download.html
2. The second error is caused by "natlog" needing "parse".  Change "depparse" to "parse":

   ```
   props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,parse,natlog,openie");
   ```

Comment: For those who download the files from the slf4j.org website, you just need to slf4j-simple-[version].jar and slf4j-api-[version].jar